# View Encapsulation issue angular5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to apply CSS to my child components that are called from a parent component using the trick it works fine

**Encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None**

But when i Navigate to other routes or pages it picks the style of the component whose Encapsulation is none weird behaiour

i.e when I hit route
http://localhost:4200/example

and Example component has

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
```

on this route there are two other components

**example.component.html**

```
<app-example1></app-example1>

<app-example2></app-example2>
```

css is apllied to the respective childerns

but when i hit example2 it also picks the css of example1

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-example2',
      templateUrl: './example2.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./example2.component.css'],


    })
```

when i remove the encapsulation property it doesn't pick for example2 route

or when i access directly the route http://localhost:4200/example2

it works fine and css only pick up the example2 css but when i navigate to example1 and naviagtes to example2

it picks the style of example 1 component because of

```
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

when i remove this property or directly access the route it works fine, what exactly is the issue I dont know why it is behaving like this

and example1 and example2 are two different modules and have its own routes

Comment: Can you share your style files as well?

Answer (score 2):

**View encapsulation** defines whether the template and styles defined within the component can affect the whole application or vice versa.

For ViewEncapsulation **None** - styles from the component propagate back to the main HTML and therefore are visible to all components on the page. Be careful with apps that have None and Native components in the application. All components with None encapsulation will have their styles duplicated in all components.

If you remove ViewEncapsulation propertythen it will take default one which is **Emulated**

In this case styles from main HTML propagate to the component. Styles defined in this component's @Component decorator are scoped to this component only.

Comment: how can i apply property of parent to specific components only

Comment: Or how can i turn off encapsulation in other components or allow in specific components

Comment: You can not do it for specific component. Either you expose to all component or keep it secret. In your case you need to make unique class at global level.

Comment: can you suggest an example for global level class

Comment: put css in style.css file

Comment: itn will behave as the same will be applied to other components too , I want only child component to take up the css

Comment: Do not use same class name everywhere. If this is not possible in your case then make CSS selector more specific.

Comment: can i remove encapsulation when component is destroyed

Comment: Encapsulation can be set only when component is defined. As per i know you can not change it in life-cycle of component. If it is possible then i do not recommend to do it as it will create confusion in future in maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

simple old css hack

Add a unique class like 
    `.app-component` to the top most element of your component, and make sure all other styles are child of this class.

Better yet if you are using any kind of css preprocessors.

Info:

When using ***ViewEncapsulation.None***, the defined styles are added to the html page using **style** tag in the **head** element.

So by ancient conventions, your styles get cascaded.

Hence when you have time invest your time in css styling conventions like *BEM* or something else.

Ciao!

Comment: Where to add the class in css file